# How to assign a float with two digits after decimal point to another float in c++

Tags: c++

First of all, I don't want to print my float. So printf("%.2f", x) doesn't work for me. I have already checked setprecision(), and it doesn't work for me.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    float obtained = 256.714964;
    float usable = 256.71; // I want to make obtained float with two digits 
                           // after decimal point without any round.
}
```

Comment: I *guess* you could do something like multiply `100`, cast to `int`, and then divide by `100.0`, but are you sure that's what you want?

Comment: Floats don't have digits. Only their string representation does. You need a fixed- place representation to have any guarantees, like represent that as `25671` with the understanding that there's a decimal in there.

Comment: No, I am calculating the average values of some datafiles. At the end, I will print them but in order to show it I need to pass the value with a parameter which has two digits after decimal point.

Comment: Why not do all your calculations with the highly-accurate values? You can still truncate decimal places when you output them, and that'll avoid accumulating errors.

Comment: No, I am using all digits in the float while making calculations, I just want to show each step what the value with format x.xx is and I have my function to show but I need to pass it as float parameter with two digits after decimal points. So, I want to assign a float to another one with two digits after decimal so that I can call my function using this parameter.

Comment: Have your print function format the number with "%.2f" like you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Remember, "output format" and "internal representation" are two different things here. The output format can have two places. The internal representation will *always* have the number of places defined by an [IEEE float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754). You can round or truncate it, but as the internal representation cannot represent all decimal values, you'll get a tiny amount of noise in your numbers.

Comment: @James you seem stubborn to understand that that's not how floating points work. Floating points aren't represented with decimal digits so no, you absolutely cannot have a `float` with just two decimal digits. The only options you have is to print the float with just two decimal digits, or to use a data type who represents real numbers with decimal digits.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About
Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a float, you could use a [ratio](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio). Do all your computations with `std::centi` (1/100ths).

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments you seem to have a difficult time understanding why you cannot have a `float` with two (or any number) of digital digits.

Please bear with me and let's make an exercise. Let's create our own data type on 3 bits who represents real numbers in the interval `[0, 50)`. Lets call it `my_type`. Because we have only 3 bits there can only be 8 values representable by our `my_type`. We want to have values distributed evenly across the interval. So we chose to go in `50 / 8 = 6.25` increments across the interval.

This is what we get:

```
Internal representation  |  Represented Value (real number)
                 (bits)  |
-------------------------+--------------------------
                     000 |  0
                     001 |  6.25
                     010 | 12.5
                     011 | 18.75
                     100 | 25
                     101 | 31.25
                     110 | 37.5
                     111 | 43.75
```

That's our data type. Only those 8 numbers are representable. When we assign a number to a `my_type` the variable will get the closest representable number. So, for instance:

```
my_type a1 = 10;      // a1 is 12.5
my_type a2 = 31.1471; // a2 is 31.25
my_type a3 = 25.789;  // a3 is 25
my_type a4 = 29.89;   // a4 is 31.25
```

Now you say: I have the number `12.67893` and I want to store in a `my_type` variable the number with just 2 digits. You can't. You simply can't. The closest value you can have is `12.5`. Let's generalize. You say I have a number with a value in the interval `[0, 50)`. I want to store it in a `my_type` variable with just two decimals. You can't. Because the internal representation of `my_type` doesn't deal with decimal digits. Some values have no decimal digits, some have 1 decimal digit and some have two. The only thing you can do is to print the `my_type` with two digits.

The story with `float` is a lot more complicated. The numbers are stored in base 2 and there are well defined rules. Some numbers represented by `float` have an infinite number of decimal digits. Some decimal numbers are not representable by `float` and the closes representable is chosen. It's true that `float` has a greater precision than our `my_type`, but the principle is the same.

If you try to represent a number with two decimal digits in a `float` you might find that that number is not representable in `float` and the closest representation is chosen. For instance instead of `x.75` you might store a number that actually is something like `x.7499999999999` or `x.7500002387`. For large numbers the precision lost is even before the dot so instead of `16'777'217.0f` you might store something like `16'777'216.0f`.

Comment: In the comment box avoid say "thanks" but how possible I don't say thanks? Thank you a lot.

Comment: @James you are welcome. You upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <cmath>

float two_decimal_places(float f) {
    return std::floor(f * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: This could turn `256.71` into something like `256.709999999483021`.

Comment: That's why this code is only sorta kinda close to a solution.

Comment: In the way I want to use, it doesn't matter how floats work or what they do. I want to show just two digits after decimal point and that's all.

Comment: @James In your question you say, "I don't want to print my float" but no you say " I want to show just two digits after decimal point and that's all". These two statements appear to contradict each other. Which is it?

Comment: Thanks for minuses, thats really helped me to feel bad as a new code learner, anyway I found the logic and is this:

Comment: int(avg * 100) / 100.0f

Comment: "Thanks for minuses" what do you mean? " thats really helped me to feel bad as a new code learner" Why? You shouldn't feel bad! You are learning and as you learn you are bound to have some misconceptions. You are going to have misconceptions even when you are an expert, just a lot less and on a more complex subjects and sometimes on simpler ones even. I distinctly remember myself doing exactly this: `int(n * 100) / 100.0f`. I had no ideea why it's wrong. I had no ideea it's wrong. We are here to help you, not to make you feel bad. We are trying to tell you how things are.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you need to learn about the difference between a floating point value and its representation as characters. You have little control over the precision of the value until you print it out.

Comment: That's more logical.

Comment: @James So the solution is to use printf() and it's formatting flags when you are ready to display the number.

Answer (score -1):

int(avg * 100) / 100.0f
Thats the logic.